# How to upcast and use child specific methods

Tags: java, xml, casting, xsd, xmlbeans

I have the following problem:

```
//class XmlObject is part of org.apache.xmlbeans
public class DepartmentType extends XmlObject; // getName method is defined in this class
public class OrganizatiopnType extends XmlObject; // getName method is defined in this class

XmlObject department = null;
if (a == 1)
    department = (DepartmentType) order.getDepartment(); // returns DepartmentType
else
    department = (OrganizationType) order.getOrganization(); // returns OrganizationType

department.getName(); // throws cannot find symbol
// ... and do some other complex stuff using methods which are defined in both classes ...
```

What is the cleanest way to call the getName() method?

UPDATE 1:
Cybernate, your approach seems the most logical, if you have control over the `DepartmentType` & `OrganizationType`. Unfortunately, these objects are generated from XML schema by xmlbeans. In my case, I *could* redesign the schema, so that both types have common base.

But what if I wouldn't have the control over the schema. How could I implement the basic idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of your schema you can define a base abstract type that your other types can extend from. I haven't tried this myself so I'm not sure how it XmlBeans will handle it.

```
<complexType name="NamedEntity" abstract="true">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="string"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="DepartmentType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="NamedEntity">
            <sequence>
                <element name="whatever"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Otherwise, it's a work-around (hack?) but you could use [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) provided your generated classes follow JavaBean naming convention.  If these objects are getting passed around a lot you could create a wrapper class to make the calls a little more concrete.

```
public class Department {
    XmlObject obj;

    public Department(XmlObject obj){
        if(!obj instanceof DepartmentType || !obj instanceof OrganizatiopnType){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return (String)PropertyUtils.getProperty(obj, "name");
    }
}
```

Any problem can be solved with another layer of indirection.....except too much indirection.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you make both classes implement a common interface, and cast to that instead. I can't see that your current casts can have any effect...

```
public interface NamedElement
{
    String getName();
}

...

NamedElement department = a == 1 ? order.getDepartment() : 
                                   order.getOrganisation();
String name = department.getName();
```

This is assuming you have control over the `DepartmentType` and `OrganizationType` code, of course.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have control over the `DepartmentType` & `OrganizationType`, they are generated externaly by xmlbeans from XSD.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is an alternative to the current class hierarchy you have.

Define a intermdeiate class called **UnitTypeBase** which **extends** from **XmlObject**.
Something like

```
public class UnitTypeBase extends XmlObject{
 public String getName(){
  //Some implementaition or you can mark it as abstract
 }
}
```

then **derive** **DepartmentType and OrganizationType** from **UnitTypeBase**

```
//class XmlObject is part of org.apache.xmlbeans 
public class DepartmentType extends UnitTypeBase; // getName method is defined in this class 
public class OrganizatiopnType extends UnitTypeBase; // getName method is defined in this class  
UnitTypeBase department = null; 
if (a == 1)     
  department = (DepartmentType) order.getDepartment(); // returns DepartmentType 
else     
     department = (OrganizationType) order.getOrganization(); // returns OrganizationType  
department.getName(); 
     // ... and do some other complex stuff using methods which are defined in both classes ...
```

Comment: I would suggest an interface instead of an intermediate class - that way if there have to be two such interfaces across different sets of classes, it'll work just fine.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, it all depends on the context.. and if the getName needs to be across different sets of classes interface based approach would be better.

Comment: what if I don't have control over the types (they are generated externaly)?

Comment: @zeldi: If you don't have control over the types then all of the solutions mentioned here are off the table. You have to then hard code the checks on each type... cast it accordingly and then call getName method... I will wait to see  if someone has a better suggestion.

Comment: I did go with the Adam B's solution, but I'd still like to hear about your alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface with method getName and both classes DepartmentType and OrganizationType implements this interface. Such as ;

```
public class IName {
   public void getName();
}

public class DepartmentType extends XmlObject implements IName {}

public class OrganizationType extends XmlObject implements IName {}

IName department = null;
if (a==1)
  department = order.getDepartment();
else
 department = order.getOrganization();
String name = department.getName();
```